# Search values & return keys only has matches in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Hi am trying to create a search suggestion by keys matches using its value.
the result of the function must return the keys matches its value only

sample array :

```
const arr = [
 { name:'Ferdinand Marlon', gender:'male',  status:'active' },
 { name:'Acey Fe', gender:'female',status:'inactive' },
 { name:'Ferry Mario', gender:'male',  status:'active' },
 { name:'Bernard Razo', gender:'male',  status:'active' },
]
```

function to call:

```
function getKeysInMatchesInValue(arr,searchValue){
  //execute search
}
```

Test

```
const t1 = getKeysInMatchesInValue(arr,"Ma")

//expected result [ 'name', 'gender' ]

const t2 = getKeysInMatchesInValue(arr,"Fe")

//expected result [ 'name', 'gender' ]

const t3 = getKeysInMatchesInValue(arr,"Fer")

//expected result [ 'name' ]

const t4 = getKeysInMatchesInValue(arr,"Ber")

//expected result [ 'name' ]

const t5 = getKeysInMatchesInValue(arr,"Ac")

//expected result [ 'name','status' ]
```

Thank you! hope someone could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get the use case behind searching keys but the following code should work for you. Assuming that keys could be anything and not only name, gender and status.

```
const arr = [
 { name:'Ferdinand Marlon', gender:'male',  status:'active' },
 { name:'Acey Fe', gender:'female',status:'inactive' },
 { name:'Ferry Mario', gender:'male',  status:'active' },
 { name:'Bernard Razo', gender:'male',  status:'active' },
]

function getKeysInMatchesInValue(arr,searchValue){
  //execute search
  let keys = [];
  arr.forEach((elem) => {
    let arrayObjKeys = Object.keys(elem);
    arrayObjKeys = arrayObjKeys.filter((k) => {
        if(elem[k].toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase())){
            return true;
      }
    })
    keys = [...keys, ...arrayObjKeys];   
  })
  return [...new Set(keys)];   //eliminate duplicates
}

const t1 = getKeysInMatchesInValue(arr,"Ma")
console.log(t1)
//expected result [ 'name', 'gender' ]

const t2 = getKeysInMatchesInValue(arr,"Fe")
console.log(t2)

//expected result [ 'name', 'gender' ]

const t3 = getKeysInMatchesInValue(arr,"Fer")
console.log(t3)
//expected result [ 'name' ]

const t4 = getKeysInMatchesInValue(arr,"Ber")
console.log(t4)
//expected result [ 'name' ]

const t5 = getKeysInMatchesInValue(arr,"Ac")
console.log(t5)
```

Attaching Fiddle for this.
https://jsfiddle.net/ahedxzcs/

Comment: Thank you it works! :) though will add improvements on this but thank your for your working idea!